# plugin version resolved twice, second time wrong version resolved

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-plugin-development

I'm trying to build `JIRA 6.0.7` from source

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/building-jira-from-source-720411927.html

It had build issues with `JDK-8` so I had to use `JDK-7`. One artifact downloads latest plugin version (although explicit version is defined in pom.xml) and fails, because of class file version.

Here's the output of `mvn -X package`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:jar:4.1.5:
[DEBUG]    com.atlassian.maven.archetypes:jira-plugin-archetype:jar:4.1.5:runtime
[DEBUG]    com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:jar:4.1.5:compile
...
[DEBUG]   Included: com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:jar:4.1.5
...
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin version for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\m2repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin to 6.2.6 from repository atlassian-proxy (https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public, releases+snapshots)
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/atlassian/maven/plugins/amps/osgi/ValidateTestManifestMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Here's simplified pom to reproduce the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
    <name>foo</name>
    <description>foo</description>


<dependencies>
</dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-proxy</id>
            <name>Atlassian Maven 2 Proxy</name>
            <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-contrib</id>
            <name>Atlassian Contrib Repository</name>
            <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/contrib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
            <id>atlassian-proxy</id>
            <name>Atlassian Maven 2 Proxy</name>
            <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Note**

`maven-amps-plugin-4.1.5.jar` is built for java 6:

```
C:\>javap -v -classpath maven-amps-plugin-4.1.5.jar com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.osgi.ValidateTestManifestMojo | find "major version"
  major version: 50
```

**Note2**

I'm so desperate, I'm now debugging maven code. https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/version/internal/DefaultPluginVersionResolver.html#L90

Before falling back to `resolveFromRepository()` it tries to `resolveFromProject()`, but fails, because `request.pom == null`. Why?

project.getBuildPlugins() returns (among many) `maven-amps-plugin` with `version == null`. Why?

```
project.getBuildPlugins().get(0)
    artifactId  "maven-jira-plugin" (id=489)    
    version "4.1.5" (id=498)    

project.getBuildPlugins().get(5)
    artifactId  "maven-amps-plugin" (id=402)    
    version null
```

Initially, a `Plugin` object is created with correct version while parsing `com/atlassian/amps/standalone/4.1.5/standalone-4.1.5.pom`, but then another instance created in `DefaultLifecyclePluginAnalyzer.parseLifecyclePhaseDefinitions()`. I guess it's caused by `<packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `maven-amps-plugin` 4.1.5, a dependency of `maven-jira-plugin` is built using JDK 8. I tried to experiment with the versions I could get, hopefully a previous version. Curiously, Maven Central has a 5.0.18 from 2015, so I mused with it, and ended up with a problem with the Oracle driver, which is OK (since Oracle drivers, if I'm not mistaken are not stored on Central). Your local repository might have it, and this snippet could help you. So even if it's unlikely the proper solution to your problem, just in case.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-amps-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.18</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: `maven-amps-plugin 4.1.5, ... is built using JDK 8`. No. Check `P.S.` in my question

Comment: How to prevent download and usage of plugin version 6.2.6 ?

Comment: True, I hasted my conclusions. mvn dependency:resolve-plugins speak of a dependency upon maven-amps-plugin-4.1.5.jar, but it is  maven-amps-plugin-6.2.6.jar that gets executed nonetheless and it is this version that is built with JDK 1.8 (1.8.0_92 to be precise). I've dug deeper, but for the moment I've no clue. The quantity of poms is quite astonishing.

Comment: Editing version in `maven-amps-plugin/maven-metadata-atlassian-proxy.xml` in local repo, but it can't be permanent solution